# Is the dielectric layer under the top or bottom copper layers always prepreg or can it be a core?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

On a PC board is the first dielectric layer looking into the board from the top or the bottom layer of copper always prepreg or can it be a core?
Here "can" would mean conventional. If not then why?

---

I asked this leaving work for the weekend. This week I asked the board house this question and they said generally prepreg is always used under the outer layers. I didnt ask why though. If no one will do it then the why doesnt really matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done either way, but conventionally the surface layers are copper foil over prepreg.

Here are two different ways to do a 6-layer board:

[image: 6lyr]

The one on the right is the standard stackup style of every board house I've used.

Comment: You can also do PPCPP as well - I've used that in one design.

Comment: You've done the left one before? Is the right one mainly better to control the board thickness? Since prepreg is pressed the thickness can be controlled right?

Comment: @Jason No, I haven't made the left one.  After I wrote this answer, I asked a related question about why these would be done. Please take [a look](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/253208/38335)!