# Are core and prepreg dielectrics interchangeable?

Tags: pcb, rf, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers

This is a followup to an [earlier question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/253198/38335).

In my experience, PCB fab houses always default to using prepreg and foil on the surface layers.  For example, on a six-layer board, the stackup would be PCPCP:

[image]

However, it is possible to use a CPCPC, and one EE.SE user [mentioned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/253198/is-the-dielectric-layer-under-the-top-or-bottom-copper-layers-always-prepreg-or?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment560403_253203) using PPCPP .

What are the considerations when choosing between these types of stackups?

Comment: A symmetrical build to avoid PCB distortion

Comment: Not a full answer, but the reason we went for PPCPP was to have four impedance controlled layers with reference planes on layers 2 and 5. The prepreg substrate being a rogers type (was a JESD204b design @ 5Gbps). Could have done 8 layers, but rogers is expensive stuff! The high speed signals were on 1 and 6, with the inner two layers being lower frequency impedance controlled signals and power lines.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Thank you, but I'm not sure I'm getting it.  Are you saying that you used rogers prepregs over a non-rogers core?

Comment: @bitsmack yes, using different dielectrics for the layers to prioritize high speed signals is definitely a thing.

Comment: @bitsmack Pretty sure we did yes - it was last year, so don't remember the specifics off the top of my head.

Comment: Ha! Just when I think I'm getting a handle on things, I always find more stuff that I didn't know about :)  Keep 'em coming!

Comment: Just checked and yes, the outer prepreg layer on each side was rogers. The inner prepreg on each side along with core were all cheaper substrate.

Comment: I have seen a number of boards like that as well (high speed dielectric with standard core).

Comment: considerations are only  controlled impedance and manufacturing ease.  If you need controlled impedances, you  should add test requirements for such and fab shop will choose best match and test with TDR coupons. If it is not critical, the no need to choose and let vendor choose, you just choose copper thickness and finished thickness.

Comment: @TonyStewart -- don't forget about embedded capacitance layers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally Core is more reproducible than Prepreg, for both thickness and dielctric constant. It is made in a factory making core to a specific thickness.

When prepreg is assembled into the final board, which usually has a finished thickness specification, the thickness of the prepreg dielectric will have an additional variation due to the variations of all the other layers. Prepreg results in a wider range of dielectric constant on the board, because the prepreg supplier is only specifying the raw material, not controlling the assembly process.

This means that controlled impedance layers should ideally be core material. However, there are different specs for controlled impedance. Logic signals do not need as much control as printed microstrip filters, so using prepreg for the former need not be an issue.

When making our 6GHz microstrip 1.6mm thick board, we used rogers 4350 core for layers 1-2 and 9-10, and FR4 with whatever mix of core/prepreg the fab house were happy with inside.