# For a 6 layer PCB, what difference does it make if we use a CPCPC vs a PCPCP? (C is for core and P for prepeg)

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, stack-up

I am working on a 6 layer PCB for motor control applicatin using Altium and the stackup being used is as follows:

Sig
GND1
PWR
Sig
GND2
Sig

I am little confused regarding the correct order of core and prepeg. Should it be CPCPC or PCPCP? And what difference does it make?
(C is for core and P for prepeg)

Comment: May I ask what do C and P stand for?

Comment: I used C for core and P for prepreg.

Comment: Thank you, I'm new to PCB Design and still learning @Umair Ali

Comment: It could also be PPCPP; any reasons not to include it?

Comment: @TimWilliams That's a very valid point. It would be like two double sided PCBs connected through core and the remaining two layers would make the top and bottom layer. It's just that most of the ones I saw had the order that I mentioned in the question. Would you like to comment on PPCPP behavior on my layer stackup?

Comment: Offhand, it looks like one major proto fab offers only PCPCP options as standard; PPCPP might not be of too much interest. I haven't shopped around on this in a while, so I'm a little curious myself.

Comment: Also, please see my related [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/253208/38335) and the answer(s) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both 'correct', in that they will both work.

However, there are some considerations

- The PCB fab will likely give you a different price on the two, depending on what they are set up to do. Ask them to quote both.
- Generally core is much better defined thickness and dielectric constant than prepreg. You will want to run defined impedance tracks with respect to a ground the other side of core.
- Generally core is thick, and prepreg is thin. This will affect which pairs of layers you want to run any low capacitance tracks on.
- In dense boards, it's very handy to use a buried core pair of layers with buried vias between them as a Manhattan (top E-W, bottom N-S routing) to give you 'unblockable' arbitrary routing. This only works with a core.
- Microvias, pretty much required if you use BGAs, require an outer prepreg/foil layer

Do you really need a power plane? Unless everything on the board works with just one rail, it's a waste of a layer that you could put signals on, and the waste of the ability to run power on other signal layers. I've always treated power as just another signal, albeit on wider tracks. If you are worried about signals crawling from one part of the board to another on power rails, then putting it all on one layer doesn't solve the problem, you still need to decouple in the right places to the right grounds, and you need to do the same to control signals.

Comment: Since my board has very tight size constraints and routing power tracks all around make it more messy. I want to be able to use that space for routing singals.